# Identifying indices of non-delimited characters in a string, supporting greater than 1 length of delimiters

Tags: java, algorithm, strings

The code below takes a string that potentially contains a true match for a delimiter. There can be multiple delimiters located anywhere in the string. We need to obtain the indices that are not a match and when the delimiter starts and ends.
The following code achieves this. However, I am unsure if this is the most optimal method. What do you think? Test cases below the code.

```
String baseText = "%!ABCD%!EF%";
String delimiter = "%";
ArrayList<String> selectedParameters = new ArrayList<>();


int lastNonDelimited = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < baseText.length()) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < delimiter.length()) {

        if (j + i == baseText.length() - 1 && j != delimiter.length() - 1) {
            lastNonDelimited += 1;
            System.out.println(lastNonDelimited);
            break;
        }

        char c = baseText.charAt(i + j);
        char d = delimiter.charAt(j);

        if (c == d) {
            if (j == delimiter.length() - 1) {
                lastNonDelimited += delimiter.length();
                i += (delimiter.length() - 1);
                System.out.println("End" + (i + j));
            } else {

                System.out.println("Beginnning" + (i + j + 1));
            }
        } else {
            lastNonDelimited += 1;
            System.out.println(lastNonDelimited);
            break;
        }

        j += 1;
    }

    i += 1;
}
```

Test case 1:

```
String %!ABCD%!EF% with %! delimiter results in: 
Beginnning1
End2
3
4
5
6
Beginnning7
End8
9
10
11
```

Test case 2:

```
String %!ABCD%!EF%! with %! delimiter results in:
Beginnning1
End2
3
4
5
6
Beginnning7
End8
9
10
Beginnning11
End12
```

Answer (score 2):

Some off the cuff comments:

It would help if you provided a compilable class rather than a somewhat misleading snippet.

Your search would be better as a separate method.

I don't see why you search in this way when String.indexof(String) and String.substring(int) exist.

Have you a clear understanding of how you would handle overlapping delimiters? If your delimiter is "!!", how is "abc!!!def" to be interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I can't easily tell its purpose.
Java code exists in files and `class`es, blocks, functions, methods, and lambdas.
With the exception of blocks, these can be named using telling names. There are conventions for "documentation" using [doc comments](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html#styleguide).

The title mentions *supporting greater than 1 length of delimiters*:
Include tests with delimiter length 1, and greater than 2.
And a test with a proper prefix of the delimiter followed by more characters. And…

Rather than declaring and initialising a *control variable* like `i` to be incremented after last use in a `while` loop, use a `for` loop.

If handling characters was the way to find delimiters (it isn't), this might look

```
/** Outputs each 1-based delimiter start and end index, 
 *  and indexes of non-delimiter characters.
 */
static void 
reportDelimiterAndNondelimiterIndexes_(String text, String delimiter) {
    final int 
        length = text.length(),
        delimiterLast = delimiter.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; ) {
        boolean startsDelimiter = true;
        for (int j = 0 ; j <= delimiterLast ; j++)
            if (length <= i + j || text.charAt(i + j) != delimiter.charAt(j)) {
                startsDelimiter = false;
                break;
            }
        i += 1;
        if (startsDelimiter) {
            System.out.println(i + " Start");
            i += delimiterLast;
            System.out.println(i + " End");
        } else
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}

// But startsDelimiter should not be reset in a loop
//  given text.startsWith(delimiter, i):

/** Prints each 1-based delimiter start and end index, 
 *  and indexes of non-delimiter characters to System.out.
 */
static void 
reportDelimiterAndNondelimiterIndexes(String text, String delimiter) {
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= text.length() ; i++)
        if (text.startsWith(delimiter, i - 1)) {
            System.out.println(i + " Start");
            i += delimiter.length() - 1;
            System.out.println(i + " End");
        } else
            System.out.println(i);
}

public static void main(String []args) {
    String
        tests[] = { "single", "lone single", 
                    "multi complete", "multi incomplete", "lone multi" },
        texts[] = { "'a'b''c'", "'", "«'»a«'»b«'»«'»c«'»", "«'a«'b«'", "«'»" },
        delimiters[] = { "'", "'", "«'»", "«'»", "«'»" };
    for (int i = 0 ; i < texts.length ; i++) {
        System.out.println(tests[i] + ':');
        reportDelimiterAndNondelimiterIndexes(texts[i], delimiters[i]);
    }
}
```

Several speed improvements are apparent: Don't (without indication of a speed problem here).

Answer (score 0):

Following code part can be changed.
There is no use with in the code for char c & char d. Hence following code can be removed

```
char c = baseText.charAt(i + j);
char d = delimiter.charAt(j);
```

And if can be used like

```
if (baseText.charAt(i + j) == delimiter.charAt(j))
```

One More way to implement this could be like this, a bit more small and possible easy to manage.

```
{
    String baseText = "%!ABCD%!EF%!";
        String delimiter = "%!";
        int i = 0;
        int length = baseText.length();
        String replaceMent = "";
        while (i < length) {
            if (i < baseText.indexOf(delimiter) || !baseText.contains(delimiter)) {
                System.out.println(i + 1);
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Beginning" + (baseText.indexOf(delimiter) + 1));
            System.out.println("End" + (baseText.indexOf(delimiter) + delimiter.length()));
            for (int j = 0; j < delimiter.length(); j++) {
                if (replaceMent.length() == 0) {
                    replaceMent = " ";
                } else {
                    replaceMent = replaceMent + " ";
                }
            }
            baseText = baseText.replaceFirst(delimiter, replaceMent);
            replaceMent = "";
            i = i + delimiter.length();
        }

}
```